# Is there any way I can verify tooltip text in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have requirement to validate tooltip text after hovering a mouse on it. is there any way for it?  tried  cy.get(ele).realHover().trigger('show').should('contain.text', text) but no luck. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: I don't get any error, simply code is not working

Comment: have you installed the cypress-real-events plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) package using `npm install cypress-real-events`
2. Register new commands by adding this to your `cypress/support/index.js` file.

```js
import "cypress-real-events/support";
```

3. In your test you can write:

```js
cy.get('selector of element').realHover()
cy.get('selector of hover text').should('be.visible').and('contain.text', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using cypress-real-events plugin as you have realHover() event command used in your code.

Try something like this:

```js
cy.get('ele').realHover();
cy.get('eleForTextFromPopup').should('be.visible').and('contains.text', 'expectedText');
```

Unfortunately you chained everything, that wont be possible in this case.
And although you are hovering the item and it gives you the expected text, you need selector for that text inside popup after hovering.